# DependencyObject.AssociatedObject is always null

Tags: wpf

I am trying to write a customer behavior to set some column widths to 0 if my "Visibility" (which is just a bool in this case) property is false... My problem is that when my on changed event fires it my AssociatedObject is always null.

Here is the relevant sample code, mybe someone can see where I am going wrong.

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Visibility", typeof(bool), typeof(HideRadGridViewColumnBehavior), 
        new PropertyMetadata(OnVisibilityPropertyChanged));

private static void OnVisibilityPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
  if (((HideRadGridViewColumnBehavior)target).AssociatedObject == null)
    MessageBox.Show("AssociatedObject is null");
}
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Go to the AssociatedObject property and make Right Button Click -> Find Usages. You will find where the property is set to null or that it isn't set at all.

Comment: Right - but this is getting set from the XAML which isn't actually generated into code until you compile the app... I mean, I am probably not saying that correctly but you get the idea, the whole point is that I won't see any references in the code to where it gets set.

Comment: After that you can put breakpoint in the setter of this property. It seems that the xaml code hasn't set the value to this property.

Answer (score 3):

how are you attaching the behavior? and can you show some code of the behavior?

the AssociatedObject is set either after the call to [Attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.behavior.attach%28Expression.40%29.aspx) or through listing the behavior within  `<i:Interaction.Behaviors></i:Interaction.Behaviors>`

Comment: This is how the behavior gets set... `   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <b:HideRadGridViewColumnBehavior Visibility="{Binding Path=DevMode}"/>
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>1

Comment: Oh - The behavior doesn't have any code yet cause the only that happens in going to be in my OnVisibilityPropertyChanged but if I don't have access to the AssociatedObject I can't do anything. :(

Comment: @Kenn, OK, then it's probably, that the binding happens before the attaching. Whatever you have in your changedhandler put that in a seperate method that you call from you changedhandler. then also override `OnAttached()` in your behavior and also call that method from there, then everything should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Markus Hütter for idea. This is how I have implemented in PasswordBox Behaviour (see comments in code below):

```
<PasswordBox>
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <behaviours:PasswordBehavior Password="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </PasswordBox>
```

Behaviour:

```
   public class PasswordBehavior : Behavior<PasswordBox>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Password", typeof(string), typeof(PasswordBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    private object _value;

    private bool _skipUpdate;

    public string Password
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PasswordProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        // in my case on OnAttached() called after OnPropertyChanged
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += PasswordBox_PasswordChanged;

        // using _value saved before in OnPropertyChanged
        if (_value != null)
        {
            AssociatedObject.Password = _value as string;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged -= PasswordBox_PasswordChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // in my case this called before OnAttached(), so that's why AssociatedObject is null on first call
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if (AssociatedObject == null)
        {
            // so, let'save the value and then reuse it when OnAttached() called
            _value = e.NewValue as string;
            return;
        }

        if (e.Property == PasswordProperty)
        {
            if (!_skipUpdate)
            {
                _skipUpdate = true;
                AssociatedObject.Password = e.NewValue as string;
                _skipUpdate = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void PasswordBox_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _skipUpdate = true;
        Password = AssociatedObject.Password;
        _skipUpdate = false;
    }
}
```