# WPF Behavior AssociatedObject is null

Tags: c#, wpf, attachedbehaviors

I'm setting a behavior on my control (in xaml), the behavior has the following code:

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    base.OnAttached();

    AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnMycontrolLoaded;
    AssociatedObject.Unloaded += OnMycontrolUnloaded;
}

private void OnMycontrolLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AssociatedObject.MyEvent +=MyEventHandler;
}

protected override void OnDetaching()
{
    base.OnDetaching();

    AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnMycontrolLoaded;
    AssociatedObject.Unloaded -= OnMycontrolUnloaded;
}
```

When I'm creating several instances of the control something weird is happening: the OnMycontrolLoaded method is called (i.e. the control/AssociatedObject is loaded) BUT inside it the AssociatedObject is null.

Why is it happening?

Comment: Any chance `OnDetached` was called before? Is the control presented in the UI or referenced in the code?

Comment: event are unregistered in OnDetaching (see edited post), the control is presented in the UI.

Comment: Can you add the xaml/code creating the behaviors and attaching them?

Comment: Can you confirm that AssociatedObject is null, but the event handler 'sender' parameter points to the object? I don't seem to be able to recreate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look where your AssociatedObject is referenced.

```
public abstract class Behavior<T> : DependencyObject, IBehavior where T : DependencyObject {

    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsable(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public T AssociatedObject { get; set; }

    protected virtual void OnAttached() {
    }

    protected virtual void OnDetaching() {
    }

    public void Attach(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject associatedObject) {
        this.AssociatedObject = (T)associatedObject;
        OnAttached();
    }

    public void Detach() {
        OnDetaching();
    }

    DependencyObject IBehavior.AssociatedObject {
        get { return this.AssociatedObject; }
    }
}
```

Look here http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/2013/windows-8-xaml-tips-creating-blend-behaviors.

Comment: And then what?  How does this answer the original problem of a null AssociatedObject?

Comment: It doesn't. This situation seems to occur when a behavior's data-bound property has a non-null value *and* the behavior is used in a template, and in my opinion it's a bug. Please see the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541702/dependencyobject-associatedobject-is-always-null for two suggested solutions.